# Request for literature recommendations on isotonic mappings

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, posets

An isotonic mapping is a function between two partially ordered sets that preserves the ordering between the elements. Specifically, given two partially ordered sets $(X,\le)$ and $(Y,\le)$, a function $f:X\to Y$ is isotonic if for any $x, y\in X$ such that $x\le y$, it is true that $f(x) \le f(y)$.

I am looking for literature recommendations on classical and generalized isotonic mappings of sets. Specifically, I am interested in any scientific and technical literature on this topic that is available in English or Russian (other languages are also acceptable). I am open to both books and articles.

If anyone is knowledgeable in this area, could you suggest where this theory is actively used? Specifically, I am interested in learning about the specific areas of mathematics and algorithms that this theory is used in.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Could you provide at least one link using this terminology? The links I've found are totally unrelated to set theory.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression) is the context in which I know *isotonic*, yours must be different?

Comment: Lattice programming?

Comment: @YCor  An isotonic mapping is a function between two partially ordered sets that preserves the ordering between the elements. Specifically, given two partially ordered sets (X, ≤) and (Y, ≤), a function f: X → Y is isotonic if for any x, y ∈ X such that x ≤ y, it is true that f(x) ≤ f(y).

Comment: I've added the definition in the post and edited the tags. I guess this is also sometimes called "order-preserving" and has several other names. I'm not sure "isotonic maps of sets" makes sense, why not "isotonic maps between posets"?

Comment: That leaves open the question of what you mean by *generalized* isotonic mappings.

Comment: @YCor I used a more general term due to my own inexperience. studying mathematics in my undergraduate degree, I did not come across such terms even in my native language, and my technical English is not good enough for a correct translation. Sorry about that, "isotonic maps between posets" is indeed more correct

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Generalized isotonic mappings of sets are functions that preserve the order of sets, but they also allow the possibility of incomparability. More formally, a function f: X → Y is isotonic if for any subsets A, B of X, if A ⊆ B and there is no x in A and y in B such that x is not comparable to y, then f(A) ⊆ f(B).

Comment: Every function $f:X\to Y$ satisfies that $A\subseteq B$ implies $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$ without any further condition.

Comment: See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The *monotonic functions* are the:

- nondecreasing functions. They are given by the isotonic mappings $(X,\le)$ and $(Y, \le)$ since $f(x)\le f(y)$ if $x\le y$.
- nonincreasing functions. They are given by the isotonic mappings $(X,\ge)$ and $(Y, \le)$ since $f(x)\le f(y)$ if $x\ge y$.
- decreasing functions. They are given by the isotonic mappings $(X,\gt)$ and $(Y, \lt)$ since $f(x)\lt f(y)$ if $x\gt y$.
- increasing functions. They are given by the isotonic mappings $(X,\lt)$ and $(Y, \lt)$ since $f(x)\lt f(y)$ if $x\lt y$.

The isotonic mappings are mainly used in the functional analysis to prove the monotonicity of some functions.